# Template arguments in constructor of non-template class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a constructor of a non-template class which is templated by a type. Can anyone help here?

```
class A
{
    public:
    static int GetId(){ return 5;}
};

class B
{
    public:
    B(int id){ _id = id;}

    template<typename T> 
    B() {_id = T::GetId();}

    template<typename T>
    static B* newB() {return new B(T::GetId());}

    private:
    int _id;
};

void doSome()
{
    B* p1 = B::newB<A>(); //works
    B* p2 = new B<A>(); //doesn't compile -- ">>B<< is no template"
}
```

Comment: template parameter for constructor should be deducible (as there is no syntax to specify template in constructor).

Comment: Use a factory algorithm and customize your construction procedure as you will.

Comment: It may be not what you want. ....  I played with it by making B a template class.   http://ideone.com/JZQgoC

Comment: @javaLover thanks for trying, but I can't make it a template class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All template parameters of a constructor template must be deducible (or have default arguments), because there is no syntax for explicitly passing template arguments to a constructor (as you've learned).

There are several possible ways around this:

1. Provide a constructor-like function template. You're already doing this with `newB`, there's just no need to force dynamic allocation:

   ```
   template <class T>
   B create() { return B(T::GetId()); }
   ```
2. Provide a tag type and parameterise the consturctor by that:

   ```
   template <class T>
   struct Tag {};

   class B
   {
   public:
     template <class T>
     B(Tag<T>) : _id(T::GetId()) {}
   };

   //usage:
   B b(Tag<A>());
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot explicitly specify the constructor template parameter. It must be deductible.

One solution is to use a helper parameter:

```
template <class T>
struct Type_holder { using Type = T; };

class B {
public:
    B(int id) : id{id} {}

    template<typename T> 
    B(Type_holder<T>) : id{T::GetId()} {}

private:
    int id;
};

auto foo()
{
    B b{Type_holder<A>{}};
}
```

Also, please use constructor initialization lists. And careful with those dynamic allocations. Don't use it if it's not needed. And when it's needed use smart pointers.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to keep my code as plain as possible, in my 'real' code I'm using initialization lists